# XML stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which inserts data into two tables like master detail format using XML format but I have one issue: while inserting into the detail section, it insert the last inserted master id as foreign key to all detail table

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================  
-- Author:  Snehal Kamath.  
-- Create date: 20-Jan-2012  
-- Description: Inserts data record in to the table.  
-- =============================================  
DECLARE 
    @projectId int,  
    @data nvarchar(max)  

BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET XACT_ABORT ON;

    BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    SET @projectId=28276
    SET @data = '<Data>
    <dt eId='''' edt=''08/27/2023'' pn=''23'' ln=''2'' qty=''12'' df1=''5447'' dq1=''3'' df2=''4379'' dq2=''3'' df3=''5469'' dq3=''3'' mf=''10/10/2020'' pkgId=''1'' ct=''1'' timeId='''' insp=''2331''>
        <DefectList>
            <Defect do=''1'' df=''5447'' dq=''3'' dc=''''/>
            <Defect do=''2'' df=''4379'' dq=''3'' dc=''''/>
            <Defect do=''3'' df=''5469'' dq=''3'' dc=''''/>
        </DefectList>
    </dt>
    <dt eId='''' edt=''08/27/2023'' pn=''4'' ln=''123'' qty=''22'' df1=''5449'' dq1=''2'' df2=''5448'' dq2=''3'' df3=''5469'' dq3=''3'' mf=''10/10/2023'' pkgId=''11'' ct=''4'' timeId='''' insp=''3''>
        <DefectList>
            <Defect do=''1'' df=''5449'' dq=''2'' dc=''''/>
            <Defect do=''2'' df=''5448'' dq=''3'' dc=''''/>
            <Defect do=''3'' df=''5469'' dq=''3'' dc=''''/>
        </DefectList>
    </dt>
</Data>';

SET IDENTITY_INSERT aoamaster ON;

DECLARE @idoc as int;

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @data;

-- Declare a variable to hold the generated aoaId
DECLARE @aoaId int;

-- Iterate through each <dt> element in the XML data
DECLARE @xmlHandle int;
DECLARE @edt nvarchar(50);

DECLARE xmlCursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT DISTINCT [edt]
    FROM OPENXML (@idoc, '/Data/dt', 1)  
    WITH (  
            edt nvarchar(50)
         );

OPEN xmlCursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM xmlCursor INTO @edt;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    ---- Generate a new aoaId
    -- SET @aoaId = NEWID(); -- You can use any method to generate a unique identifier

    -- Insert data into AOAMaster for the current <dt> element
    INSERT INTO AOAMaster  
            (
                [aoaProjectId],  
                [aoaDate],  
                [aoaPartNumber],  
                [aoaLotNumber],  
                [aoaMfgDate],  
                [aoaPkgId],  
                [aoaCert123],  
                [aoaQtySorted],  
                [aoaDefect1],  
                [aoaQty1],  
                [aoaDefect2],  
                [aoaQty2],  
                [aoaDefect3],  
                [aoaQty3],  
                [aoaInspector],
                [aoaPallet]
            )  
        SELECT   
            @projectId,  
            TemplateData.edt, TemplateData.pn,  
            TemplateData.ln, TemplateData.mf,  
            TemplateData.pkgId, TemplateData.ct,  
            TemplateData.qty, TemplateData.df1,  
            TemplateData.dq1, TemplateData.df2,  
            TemplateData.dq2, TemplateData.df3,  
            TemplateData.dq3, TemplateData.insp,  
            TemplateData.pl
        FROM 
            OPENXML (@idoc, '/Data/dt', 1)  
            WITH   
            (  
                eId int,  
                edt nvarchar(50),  
                pn nvarchar(50),  
                ln nvarchar(50),  
                mf nvarchar(50),  
                pkgId nvarchar(50),  
                ct nvarchar(50),  
                qty int,  
                df1 int,  
                dq1 int,  
                df2 int,  
                dq2 int,  
                df3 int,  
                dq3 int,  
                pl nvarchar(50),  
                insp nvarchar(50)  
            ) as TemplateData
            WHERE TemplateData.edt = @edt; -- Filter by the current <dt> element

             SET @aoaId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();


            -- Insert data into AOADefectList for the current <dt> element
            INSERT INTO AOADefectList 
            (
                [aoaId],
                [aoaDefectOrder],
                [aoaDefect],
                [aoaDefectQty],
                [aoaDefectComment]
            )
            SELECT 
                @aoaId,
                defect.do,
                defect.df,
                defect.dq,
                defect.dc
            FROM OPENXML (@idoc, '/Data/dt[edt=sql:variable("@edt")]/DefectList/Defect', 1)  
            WITH   
            (
                do int,
                df nvarchar(50),
                dq int,
                dc nvarchar(100)
            ) as defect;

            FETCH NEXT FROM xmlCursor INTO @edt;
        END;

        CLOSE xmlCursor;
        DEALLOCATE xmlCursor;

        EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @idoc;
        COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

        THROW;
    END CATCH;
END;
```

Comment: Don't forget to add a tag for the dbms used. (The above code is product specific. Perhaps MS SQL Server?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is likely due to how you're setting the `@aoaId` variable within the loop. Since you're setting it inside the loop and using `SET @aoaId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();`, it's being overwritten with the last inserted master ID in each iteration of the loop. To fix this, you should generate a new `@aoaId` for each master record and use it consistently for the corresponding detail records.
So comment the `SET @aoaId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();` line and check.

Comment: But aoaId  is auto increment column.